# how to fix konga_db

Tags: postgresql, docker, kong

this is docker me

```py
0e60f32df539        pantsel/konga:legacy                                               "/app/start.sh"          3 days ago          Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:1337->1337/tcp                                               konga
da8fe5294057        kong                                                               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 days ago          Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000-8001->8000-8001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443-8444->8443-8444/tcp   kong
0caeee73418b        postgres:9.6                                                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 days ago          Up 34 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                                               kong-database
```

i try to install

```py
docker run --rm --network=kong-net pantsel/konga -c prepare -a postgres -u postgresql://kong@kong-database:5432/konga_db
```

this is error

```py
debug: Preparing database...
Using postgres DB Adapter.
Failed to connect to DB { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND kong-database kong-database:5432
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'kong-database',
  host: 'kong-database',
  port: 5432 }
```

how to fix error?

Comment: Does your `kong-database` container also use the network `kong-net`? Update the result of `docker network inspect kong-net` to question please.

Answer (score 1):

As the error implies that it's not able to find the domain name you are referring for PostgreSQL. try to change the kong-database to exact hostname i.e "localhost" if you are running all docker containers on same VM.

The command should be as below :

```
docker run --rm --network=kong-net pantsel/konga -c prepare -a postgres -u postgresql://kong@localhost:5432/konga_db
```

As @atline suggest please also confirm your docker network, confirm with `docker network ls` it should respond as below:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
3a03dfb71f30        bridge              bridge              local
0501e0af7350        kong-net            bridge              local
1decf874e725        host                host                local
adc2bd16eaa3        none                null                local
```